# Are Questions with bounties that only Salesforce Employees can answer fair?

Tags: discussion, bounty

You may find a recent example [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196204/status-of-usage-metrics-is-it-dead-or-is-there-a-roadmap)

I wonder if it is in the spirit of SFSE to award bounties for answers that only SF employees can share with any claim to credibility.

Answer (score 4):

I certainly think it is fair to offer a bounty. We all benefit from such knowledge being shared.

Comment: I agree.  I wish more SF employees answered questions on SFSE.